# sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in "Ruta de archivo"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

la verdad no se me ocurre porque pueda pasar esto... soy nuevo usando SQLServer con PHP ya que siempre he usado MariaDB o MySQL, pero bueno... Lo que quiero hacer es un select que muestre datos de 2 tablas diferentes con inner join ya que pretendo usar DataTables para esto, y me está mostrando este error en navegador.

```
 sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in "La ruta del archivo y la linea 25"
```

Exactamente esto es lo que se ejecuta en la linea 25 como dice el error

```
$row = sqlsrv_has_rows($sql);
```

que hace parte de esto:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $sql);

$tabla="";

if ($sql !== NULL) {
    $row = sqlsrv_has_rows($sql); //<-- Este es donde muestra la linea con error
    if ($row === true)  {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC )){

            $tabla=$tabla.'<tr>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato3'].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato4'].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato5'].'</td>
            <td>'.$datos['Dato6'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
}
//print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);

    sqlsrv_close($conexion);

    echo '<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
    <th>Dato1</th>
    <th>Dato2</th>
    <th>Dato3</th>
    <th>Dato4</th>
    <th>Dato5</th>
    <th>Dato6</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'.$tabla.'
    </tbody>';

    ?>
```

Antes de este último código está la consulta de las tablas, no me pareció necesario agregarlo ya que considero que ese error no tiene que ver con eso... Muchas gracias a quien ayude con este problema de antemano!

Comment: Deberías pasarle `$result`, algo así: **`sqlsrv_has_rows($result);`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indica [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-has-rows.php), el parámetro que debe pasarse a `sqlsrv_has_rows` tiene que ser un recurso, o conjunto de resultados obtenido mediante `sqlsrv_query()` o `sqlsrv_execute()`.

> A statement resource returned by `sqlsrv_query()` or `sqlsrv_execute()`.

En tu código ese recurso se encontraría en la variable `$result`, que es la que recupera el resultado de `sqlsrv_query()`, pero tú le estás pasando la cadena `$sql` que no es otra cosa que la consulta, no los resultados que la ejecución de ésta ha traído.

Si lo cambias así debería funcionar, salvo errores adicionales:

```
$row=sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
```

Por otra parte, comentes el mismo error en la lectura, usas `$sql` de nuevo. Esa cadena no pinta nada ahí, los datos estarían en `$result` que es el recurso que devolvió la consulta.

Y cometes otro error ahí, el código es incoherente: estás solicitando un `fetch` numérico, pero en la lectura dentro del `while` usas un estilo asociativo.

Para corregirlo, ponlo así:

```
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Asumo que `Dato1, Dato2, Dato3` son nombres de columna. Si quieres implementar un *fetch numérico*  puedes ponerlo así:

```
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){
```

Pero la lectura en ese cado debe ser así: `$row[0], $row[1], $row[2]`, etc...

Sugiero que revises la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) para entender la diferencia de los estilos de lectura de resultado.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, debe ser el sueño o algo... estaba recogiendo la consulta mas no el resultado... llevo 3 días sin dormir 

Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Dante revisa lo que puse al final de la respuesta, pues tienes errores en la forma de lectura de los datos también. En fin, a veces conviene parar un poco, reposar y luego retomar y cuando las cosas se compliquen, acude a Stackoverflow, que está para ayudarnos unos a otros.

Comment: Si lo haría, pero estoy muy retrasado con este proyecto por pandemia y otras cosas, hacer soporte a los usuarios es mas lento via remota que presencial, y eso me ha quitado mucho tiempo, llevo aproximadamente un 50% del proyecto en estos momentos, y lo ideal es tenerlo finalizado en 1 semana desde esta fecha,  y como no tengo auxiliar ahora entonces pues... pero si hoy dormiré temprano , gracias nuevamente!